# PHP, The Closure class

Tags: php, class, closures

I am trying to understand about the closure class, at the manual there is, 
All at the manual [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php),

**Closure::__construct** - Constructor that disallows instantiation. If i understand it right the only instance of this class is for anonymous function variable assignment.

But i did not understand few lines:

**Closure::bind** — Duplicates a closure with a specific bound object and class scope.

**Closure::bindTo** — Duplicates the closure with a new bound object and class scope.

And the last at the manual i did not understand this sentence:

> Besides the methods listed here, this class also has an __invoke
>   method. This is for consistency with other classes that implement
>   calling magic, as this method is not used for calling the function.

If can some one please try to explain thoes lines to me i will be very thankful, Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you all i am reading the answers now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is referring to the [calling magic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke).

As my understanding, for any class that contains the method `__invoke` which its instances can be called as if it is a function. The `Closure::__invoke` acts like that.

i.e. when `$foo` is of class `Closure` (anonymous function), calling `$foo($bar)` will call `$foo->__invoke(bar)` (although the `__invoke` member is not meant to be called directly, this is just to show how it works).

When you define anonymous functions, you do this:

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};
```

Now, `$greet` is of class `Closure`. and `$greet->__invoke` is sort of equal to `function($name){ printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name); }`

And remember, `Closure::__invoke` is a [Magic Method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke).

Comment: Thank you Alvin Wong for you explanation about the __invoke Magic Method i also know now on another magic method witch i can use at OOP so thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

I think the difference between `bind` and `bindTo` is just in the way they're called:

```
$cl->bindTo($obj)
```

is equivalent to

```
Closure::bind($cl, $obj)
```

Regarding the `__invoke` meethod, it's saying that the method exists, but it's not actually used. When you use the closure as a function, an internal (probably more efficient) mechanism is used that bypasses the method. But the method is there for compatibility with other classes that are callable, and you could call it manually if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you Barmar can you please expand a bit more about bind and bindTo becouse i dont know if i got this right if you can compare bindTo and bind to a code please.

Comment: as [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) states that `This method is a static version of Closure::bindTo().`

Comment: Look at the examples in the documentation. I don't think I can do any better than that. They're just two different ways of writing the exact same thing -- bindTo is object-oriented, while bind is traditional function style.